# Can't get Bootstrap ToolTip working on column which has Popover assigned at row level

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip, popover

I am using DataTables to display data and on every row, I am adding some data so that whenever user hover over a particular row, he gets a `popover` with extra data like

`<tr id="123" class="Search odd" data-title="Profile data" data-content=" <p> <label>Test Popover</label> </p>" data-original-title="" title="">

</tr>`

whenever user hover a row, he gets `Popover` with Test Popover as text, now I am adding couple of column to it like

`<td class=" sorting_1">Name</td>

    <td class="">somedate</td>

    <td class="">

    <img title="Test tooltip" rel="tooltip" src="/img/paid_small.png">

    </td>`

My javascript on page ready is

`$('.Search').live('hover', function (e) {
        $('.Search').popover({ 'trigger': 'hover', 'placement': 'right', 'container': 'body', 'html': true });
    });`

`$('[rel=tooltip]').tooltip({ 'placement': 'bottom', 'container': 'body' });`

As you can see, I have added javascript for both `popover` and `Tooltip` but for some reason `Tooltip` css doesnt work and I kind of get windows kind of `Tooltip` (light grey tooltip with my data) rather than `Bootstrap` black background one. I have tried creating dummy link with `ToolTip` somewhere else in a page and it doesn work.

It looks like `Popover` is overriding `ToolTip` in this particular case or maybe I am trying to display `Popover` (at row level) and `ToolTip` (column level) at same time and that maybe causing the problem.

Any idea why this may be happening?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed: I add `Tooltip` javascript under `Search --> Hover` event, Final Javascript looks something like

`$('.Search').live('hover', function (e) {

$('.Search').popover({ 'trigger': 'hover', 'placement': 'right', 'container': 'body', 'html': true });
$('[rel=tooltip]').tooltip({ 'placement': 'bottom', 'container': 'body' });
});`

Sorry couldnt figure out how to properly inddent javascript.